# Anime series in which the main character finds a gumball machine under a tree and summons monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was a kid, I used to see this anime on Netflix where the main character finds a gumball machine with many balls inside it under a tree and opens it and summons some kind of monster. I remember only that part and that one of the monsters could make people sleepy when it's nearby.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: This is probably a "gatcha" machine, with capsules containing things, not gumballs, but I won't swear to it, so I won't edit that in.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it could be [Yo-kai Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-kai_Watch). In the first episode, which you can watch on YouTube (shown below), the main character releases the yokai Whisper from a gatcha dispenser under a tree.

From a search of the episode descriptions on Wikipedia, episode 19 includes a plot about a yokai sending people to sleep. Wikipedia also mentions that the show was previously on Netflix, but not any more.